# multer-sharp-s3 not running with docker node alpine

Tags: node.js, docker, multer, sharp, multer-s3

Docker restarts after

```
 require('multer-sharp-s3');
 //or
 require('sharp');
```

**`lovell/sharp`** stops Node docker without logging any error

```
Docker Restarting (139) 37 seconds ago
```

Github issue : https://github.com/ikhsanalatsary/multer-sharp-s3/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

for Nodejs Docker use

`FROM lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x`

it works fine with cpp support

Documentation source https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/master/docs/install.md

The **multer-sharp-s3** not mentioned any docker requirement neither logged any error